# File not found when using Drive.Files.get(path)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to automate attaching and sending emails using Gscripts. Each recipient has his own unique attachment so I have a Google sheet containing the details:

Column A contains the email addresses.
Column B contains the message.
Column D contains the filename of the attachment along with the file extension.

Here's my code:

```
function sendEmails() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var rowEmails = sheet.getRange(1,1,3);
   var rowMessage = sheet.getRange(1,2,3);
   var rowAttachments = sheet.getRange(1,4,3);

   var vEmails = rowEmails.getValues();
   var vMessage = rowMessage.getValues();
   var vAttachments = rowAttachments.getValues()


for (i in vEmails) {
   var emailAddress = vEmails[1] + '';
   var message = vMessage[1];
   var subject = "Test"
   var path = 'certs\\' + vAttachments[i]    
   var file = Drive.Files.get(path);
   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, vMessage[1], {attachments: files});
}
}
```

Everything works well but when it comes to var file = Drive.Files.get(path), I get an error saying no file is found. I checked my drive and I'm sure it is there. I've also checked the Drive API. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: I don't see any `Drive.Files.get(path)` there's a `Drive.Files.get(FileId)` and also another one that has an object for optional parameter but they both require fileId. Also I believe attachments requires an array of files and  I don't believe that your variable files is even defined.

Comment: `var emailAddress = vEmails[1] + '';` vEmails is a two dimensional array

Comment: What are the values stored in `D1:D3`? Are they file names or file ids?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be a little closer to working:

```
function sendEmails() {
   var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var Emails=sheet.getRange(1,1,3).getValues();
   var Message=sheet.getRange(1,2,3).getValues();
   var fileids=sheet.getRange(1,3,3).getValues();//you need to add file ids
  Emails.forEach(function(r,i){
    MailApp.sendEmail(Emails[i][0],"Test",Message[i][0],{attachments:[DriveApp.getFileById(fileids[i][0])]});
  });
}
```

Comment: This is assuming that the spreadsheet has the files ids on `C1:C3`

Comment: It works! Thank you! My only problem now is getting the file IDs of all 500 images. I don't have a list of it, just their file name. Is there a way to automate it? Sorry I'm new to Gscripts.

Comment: If you can find the images by name then you can make a list of the ids.  Get use to using id's of files and not names.  Files always have unique id's but not necessarily unique names.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question has several flaws:

1. `path` : Google Drive doesn't use "path"
2. `for in` / `vAttachments[i]`: a different *property name* is assigned to the variable on each iteration but `vAttachments` hasn't named properties, so `vAttachments[i]` will return `null` on each iteration.
3. The files property on the options should be an Array.

How to "fix" the script

1. The way to directly get files in Google Drive is by using file ids.
2. If you want to get files by "path", first your script should get the folder, then look for the file inside that folder but bear in mind that getting a folder/file by name returns a folder/file iterator
3. Instead of [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) use [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) or use [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) (most of the scripts I have seen usen use `for`)